# Maximal hausdorff dimension in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Is it true that any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has at most $n$ as Hausdorff dimension ?

Comment: If all you want is a confirmation, then yes.

Comment: I want to know also how to prove this, or  the idea behind

Comment: You should show that for any set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $d>n$, the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff content of $S$ is $0$. What have you tried?

Comment: You can show that by showing that $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$ for $s>n$,  I can write a proof if you need it

Comment: I tried to prove it, but couldn't, if you can write it, I'd be glad.

Comment: I think it's quite easy to show that an $n$-dimensional cube has finite $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. A simple corollary is that any bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$ has finite $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. $\sigma$ additivity then yields your desired result.